# Clip canvas strokes to image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to animate a pen filling in a variable width shape, currently working with html5 canvas.  Ideally, I want to be able to have the sample below both start light and get colored in dark, as well as not appear at all and get colored in as though being drawn from nothing.

source-in doesn't seem to work, at least in firefox.

The image in question is a simple-ish SVG path, so if there's a reasonable way to generate canvas clip paths from SVG bezier paths, that would work as well.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,...";

var xRecords = [...];
var yRecords = [...];

var canvas = document.getElementById("topCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000ff";
ctx.lineWidth = 90;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.moveTo(xRecords[0], yRecords[0]);

for(var i = 0; i < xRecords.length; i++) {
   ctx.lineTo(xRecords[i], yRecords[i]);
   ctx.stroke();
}
```

http://codepen.io/matelich/pen/gpLmOW

Generating alternate versions of the image is not a big deal if that would help. Oh and the animation is just a sample.

---

*Update* This works for the most part on Chrome and IE, but not on Firefox: http://codepen.io/matelich/pen/pJNeRq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FF doesn't like your SVG dataURL.

Option#1:

You could use a .png image instead.

Option#2:

You can create a cubic Bezier curve (like SVG's "C") in canvas using `context.moveTo` and `context.bezierCurveTo`.

Then your compositing will work fine even in FF:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("topCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/svg2png.png';
var xRecords = [117.6970666666671, 137.5037866666671, 139.6247579166671, 138.2627966666671, 134.75555041666712, 130.4406666666671, 126.65579291666711, 124.7385766666671, 126.0266654166671, 131.8577066666671, 155.5330366666671, 191.76562666666712, 224.94953666666714, 239.47882666666712];
var yRecords =  [143.95648000000128, 200.21077333333463, 232.21213000000128, 264.735546666668, 296.24260333333467, 325.19488000000126, 350.05395666666794, 369.2814133333347, 381.33883000000134, 384.687786666668, 371.9640133333346, 346.7872000000013, 322.15182666666794, 311.05237333333463];

function start(){
  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0, 0, 640, 640);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "darker";
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000ff";
  ctx.lineWidth = 90;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.moveTo(xRecords[0], yRecords[0]);

  var i = 0;
  function drawNext() 
  { 
    i++;
    console.log(i+"!");
    if(i >= xRecords.length) { return; }
    ctx.lineTo(xRecords[i], yRecords[i]);
    ctx.stroke();
    setTimeout(drawNext, 500);
  }
  drawNext();

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="topCanvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Looks like I could probably use canvg to create my clip path - or convert my svg to png client-side maybe.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of graphic creations in Adobe Illustrator then you might check out Mike Swanson's great AI add-on that converts an Illustrator drawing to html5 canvas drawing commands: http://blog.mikeswanson.com/post/55803115171/ai-canvas-1-2-for-illustrator-cc-and-cs6